# Check are there lowercase characters in string

Tags: string, common-lisp, lowercase

I need return True or False

- `True` if at least one lowercase character
- `False` no lowercase characters

I tried do it with loop and lambda function 
Something like this

```
(defun check-lower-word (word)
    (loop
        for ch across word 
        ((lambda (c) (if (lower-case-p c) return T) ch)
    )
)
```

I need False if never worked "if"

Comment: Welcome to SO! While @Renzo has answered your question perfectly you should consider read some basic remarks about CL [style](https://lisp-lang.org/style-guide/) and even more important general [introductions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/common-lisp/info) to CL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a predefined function, you could use `some` ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#some)):

```
CL-USER> (some #'lower-case-p "AbC")
T
CL-USER> (some #'lower-case-p "ABC")
NIL
```

There is a similar operation for the `loop` syntax ([manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#some)):

```
CL-USER> (loop for x across "AbC" thereis (lower-case-p x))
T
CL-USER> (loop for x across "ABC" thereis (lower-case-p x))
NIL
```

Finally, note that `loop` always returns `nil` when the iteration terminates without producing a result, so a less concise use of `loop` could be:

```
CL-USER> (loop for x across "AbC" if (lower-case-p x) do (return t))
T
CL-USER> (loop for x across "ABC" if (lower-case-p x) do (return t))
NIL
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Code errors

You code is not balanced with respect to parentheses, there is a missing closing parenthesis at the end:

```
(defun check-lower-word (word)
    (loop
        for ch across word 
        ((lambda (c) (if (lower-case-p c) return T) ch)
    )
) ; <-- closes "(loop"
```

The syntax error in your `loop` should have raised an error, it does not make sense to write an expression `EXPR` directly in `(loop for c across w EXPR)`, there should be a preceding `do`.

The literal `((lambda (c) E) ch)` can be directly written as `E` where every occurence of the variable `c` is substituted by `ch`, namely:

```
(if (lower-case-p ch) return T)
```

The use of an intermediate literal lambda brings nothing here.

Also, the above reads as: *if `ch` is lowercase, the value of the if is the value bound to the `return` variable, otherwise it is T*. You are indeed missing parens around `(return T)`. A "one-armed" `(if T X)` is best written as `(when T X)`.

#### Another approach

You already have an example with `some` and `loop`, you can also use a short-circuiting `map`:

```
(defun check-lower-word (word)
  (block nil
    (map ()
         (lambda (c)
           (when (lower-case-p c)
             (return t)))
         word)))
```

A call to [`MAP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm) with `nil` as a first argument means the sequence is iterated for effects and returns nil. For each character in the sequence (list or vector), when the character is lower-case, return T. The `return` exits the iteration early up to the NIL block.

Answer (score 0):

I did it as

```
(defun check-lower-word (word)
    (block outer
        (loop
            for ch across word do
                (if (lower-case-p ch) (return-from outer T))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If you use `return-from` anyway, you can use the implicit block established by and named after the function itself: `(return-from check-lower-word t)`.